# Can someone help me with a SOAP Request in PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I need to generate following SOAP Request with PHP:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:post="http://post.ondot.at" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:core="http://Core.Model" xmlns:ser="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <post:ImportShipment>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <post:row>
            <post:DeliveryServiceThirdPartyID>10</post:DeliveryServiceThirdPartyID>
                <post:OURecipientAddress>
                    <post:AddressLine1>Teststrasse</post:AddressLine1>
                    <post:AddressLine2/>
                    <post:City>Wien</post:City>
                    <post:CountryID>AT</post:CountryID>
                    <post:Email/>
                    <post:HouseNumber>1</post:HouseNumber>
                    <post:Name1>Test Recipient</post:Name1>
                    <post:PostalCode>1030</post:PostalCode>
                </post:OURecipientAddress>
                <post:OUShipperAddress>
                    <post:AddressLine1>Musergasse</post:AddressLine1>
                    <post:City>Wien</post:City>
                    <post:CountryID>AT</post:CountryID>
                    <post:Name1>test &amp; test</post:Name1>
                    <post:Name2/>
                    <post:PostalCode>1010</post:PostalCode>
                </post:OUShipperAddress>
                <post:PrinterObject>
                    <post:LabelFormatID>100x150</post:LabelFormatID>
                    <post:LanguageID>PDF</post:LanguageID>
                    <post:PaperLayoutID>A5</post:PaperLayoutID>
                </post:PrinterObject>
            </post:row>
        </post:ImportShipment>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I tried is following:

```
$parcelData = [
    'row' => [
        'DeliveryServiceThirdPartyID' => 10,
        'OURecipientAddress' => [
            'AddressLine1' => 'Teststrasse',
            'City' => 'Wien',
            'CountryID' => 'AT',
            'HouseNumber' => '1',
            'Name1' => 'Test Recipient',
            'PostalCode' => '1030',
        ],
        'OUShipperAddress' => [
            'AddressLine1' => 'Musergasse',
            'City' => 'Wien',
            'CountryID' => 'AT',
            'Name1' => 'test & test',
            'PostalCode' => '1010',
        ],
        'PrinterObject' => [
            'LabelFormatID' => '100x150',
            'LanguageID' => 'PDF',
            'PaperLayoutID' => 'A5',
        ],
    ],
];

$response = $this->client->ImportShipment($parcelData);
```

But always getting a Bad Request Error no matter what I tried.
Unfortunately I have no experience with SOAP Request and WSDL in PHP.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: If you feed the WSDL to [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/resources/tutorials/soap-sample-project/) and make the same call, does it work?